# An interesting geometric fact

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

> [image]

In this question, I accidentally proved that the triangle A1B1C1 is the scaled up version  of the pedal Triangle. Is this proof valid?  By the way would someone please help me to solve this question? I have tried using the Euler line but that didn't help me out.

Comment: Which pedal triangle do you mean? And how a proof can be validated if not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints for answering the question:

For a triangle $ABC$ with circumcenter at the origin of the complex plane the following statements hold:

1. The orthocenter $H$ is given by:
   $$h=a+b+c.$$
2. The point $A_1$ (the intersection point of the circumcircle with the altitude drawn from $A$) is given by:
   $$
   a_1=-\frac{bc}a.
   $$

Can you take it from here?